# Information about SCO Unix Com ports

Tags: unix, serial-port

I am trying to talk to a SCO Unix box through the Serial Port where there an existing application. I need to figure out what parameters the application set the serial port too. This is an older non-GUI version of Unix so I need to be able to do this from the command line.

I know it involves using  /dev/tty* however I am having difficulty finding any specific documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring serial ports can be done from:

> /usr/lib/uucp/Devices

For testing 'cu' command is suitable

Answer (score 0):

Check out stty.

(I have no knowledge of SCO, but this is the generic Unix way to handle serial ports).